# How to return mousewheel scroll event when unbind is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am working with a site that have a Chart on the middle which is scroll able to zoom-in and zoom-out using mouse scroll but my problem is when i scroll the page overflow or whole body is also scrolling i have tried this block of code the binding for stop scrolling it is working on the chart but i cannot unbind or return it back to the original when i am scrolling outside the Chart. Below is the code that i am using. I have also tried to changing the function to return true and still not working.

BindScroll

```
      $('body').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', lockScroll);
```

unbind scroll

```
      $('body').unbind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', lockScroll);


      function lockScroll(e) {
           e.preventDefault();
      }
```

Comment: of course your bind it to the body instead of the Chart's DOM object.

Comment: Can you explain it to me clearly sorry for not understanding well. I'm preventing the whole page from scrolling so that's why i used the body while the mousewheel on chart is still working.

Comment: $('.chart').mouseleave(function(){ $('body').unbind...

Comment: Hi @Wils Thanks for your help it is now working on my end :)

Answer (score 0):

Instand of unbinding, just ignore the mouse wheel event.

```
var mindingMousewheel = true
```

set it to false when you don’t want to watch it. And test it before you do anything.

```
$('body').bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta) {
          if (! mindingMousewheel) return;
})
```